# How to give break line in data label

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

how to give break line in data label , Till what i have done below is link and i have pasted code here also.

And i am using custom datalabel and i want to add break line

https://jsfiddle.net/0x3ct8aq/4/

```
<script>

    onComplete () {

       const chartInstance = this.chart;
      const ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
      const dataset = this.data.datasets[0];
      const meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(0);

      Chart.helpers.each(meta.data.forEach((bar, index) => {

        const label = this.data.customlabels[index];
        const labelPositionX = 20;
        const labelWidth = ctx.measureText(label).width + labelPositionX;

        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
        console.log(label.x);
        ctx.fillText(label, bar._model.x, bar._model.y);

      }));


    }
  } 
    },



});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `animation.onComplete()` function, you can [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the labels array, then draw individual tokens using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) as follows:

```
label.reverse().forEach((l, i) => ctx.fillText(l, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - (i * 16)))
```

Please have a look at your amended [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/42cvofqu/)